# How to switch to other running application

Tags: android, android-intent, switch-statement

I want to write a application to switch to other running application, like "Switch to" on "Windows Task Manager".

I already have it's package name, process name, pid, label. But I don't know how to switch to it. Pls help me! Thank U!

P/S: I'm thinking about use Intent, but Intent.setClassName (String pkname, String cls name) need class name and i don't know how to get it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is an easy one.

```
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) inst.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for(RunningTaskInfo t: am.getRunningTasks(10)){
        String packageName = t.topActivity.getPackageName();
        String className = t.topActivity.getClassName();
    }
    //Which one do you want?
    //Could also just do
    String packageName = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
    String className = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getClassName();

    //then
    startActivity(new Intent().setClassName(packageName, className).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    //Keep in mind you will need to declare the following permission in your AndroidManifest.xml
    android.Manifest.permission.GET_TASKS
```

Comment: You beat me for a few seconds :)

Comment: Thanks for the up vote, trying to make a rep, and making good use of being up late!

Comment: Thank you. I have one more question. I already have packet name of the application call "ABC" i want to switch to: com.abc. So how can i get the topActivity.className of ABC?

Comment: Sorry fo the way code looks in the comments, but If you already have the "package" name then when you loop...         `String className = "";                                        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager);                  inst.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for(RunningTaskInfo t: am.getRunningTasks(10)){
        if(t.topActivity.getPackageName()).contains("com.abc"){
            className = t.topActivity.getClassName();                                                                                     }
    }`

Comment: @rogerl: not to nit-pick but you missed a closing parenthesis on your startActivity(), and "android.Manifest.permission.GET_TASKS" should be "android.permission.GET_TASKS" :P

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> getRunningTasks();
```

Returns a list of tasks that are running on the device.

If you look at the `RunningTaskInfo` API, there is a field `public ComponentName baseActivity`

ComponentName, on has these two public methods:

```
String getClassName()
```

Return the class name of this component.

```
String getPackageName()
```

Return the package name of this component.

```
     ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
     for (ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo info : am.getRunningTasks(9999)){
         int id = info.id;
         Log.d ("AM", "ID: " + id);
         String name = info.baseActivity.getClassName();
         Log.d ("AM", "Class: " + name);
     }
```